# How to create a k8s configmap by looping over nested helm values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

The helm values look like in the following example. Here `appdata` can scale to any number but will contain the same set of keys.

```
data:
  appdata:
    config0:
      url: 'https://example1.com'
      port: '80'
    config1:
      url: 'https://example2.com'
      port: '8673'
    someotherconfig:
      url: 'https://example3.com'
      port: '9887'
    ...
    ...
```

This is what I have so far. This keeps updating the last config's data from `someotherconfig` key and also I want to have the config map name to contain the config name for each iteration, like {{ template "app" $ }}-config0, {{ template "app" $ }}-config1 and so on based on iteration.

```
{{- range $Mydata := $.Values.data.appdata }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app" $ }}
  labels:
data:
  url: {{ $Mydata.url }}
  port: {{ $Mydata.port }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to use the key/value notation to get the key name. Try the following.

```
{{- range $configuration, $Mydata := $.Values.data.appdata }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app" $ }}-{{ $configuration }}
data:
  url: {{ $Mydata.url }}
  port: {{ $Mydata.port }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Works as needed. Thank you. Is it possible to populate a default value in case the url or port is not available in values ?

Comment: Try doing this, {{ $Mydata.url | default "localhost" | quote }}